# Does the future depend on me alone?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, zohar

I read in a book that the Zohar says that everyone should consider himself as if the future of the world  depended on him alone. Where does it say that, and does the idea originate elsewhere?  I know the Talmud says that everyone should assume the world was created for him alone, but this is different.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found it in the Zohar, but in the Gemara it is an extension of the view of the Sages as expressed by Rabbi Elazar B'Rabi Shimon ([Kiddushin 40b](https://www.sefaria.org/Kiddushin.40b.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en&p3=Mishneh_Torah%2C_Repentance.3.4&lang3=bi)):

> ת"ר לעולם יראה אדם עצמו כאילו חציו חייב וחציו זכאי עשה מצוה אחת אשריו
> שהכריע עצמו לכף זכות עבר עבירה אחת אוי לו שהכריע את עצמו לכף חובה
> שנאמר (קהלת ט, יח) וחוטא אחד יאבד טובה הרבה בשביל חטא יחידי שחטא אובד
> ממנו טובות הרבה ר' אלעזר בר' שמעון אומר לפי בשהעולם נידון אחר רובו
> והיחיד נידון אחר רובו עשה מצוה אחת אשריו שהכריע את עצמו ואת כל העולם
> לכף זכות עבר עבירה אחת אוי לו שהכריע את עצמו ואת כל העולם לכף חובה
> שנאמר וחוטא אחד כו' בשביל חטא יחידי שעשה זה אבד ממנו ומכל העולם טובה
> הרבה
>
> Our Rabbis taught: A man should always regard himself as though he
> were half guilty and half meritorious: if he performs one precept,
> happy is he for weighting himself down in the scale of merit; if he
> commits one transgression, woe to him for weighting himself down in
> the scale of guilt, for it is said, but one sinner destroyeth much
> good: [i.e.,] on account of a single sin which he commits much good is
> lost to him. R. Eleazar son of R. Simeon said: Because the world is
> judged by its majority, and an individual [too] is judged by his
> majority [of deeds, good or bad], if he performs one good deed, happy
> is he for turning the scale both for himself and for the whole world
> on the side of merit; if he commits one transgression, woe to him for
> weighting himself and the whole world in the scale of guilt, for it is
> said: ‘but one sinner, etc.’ — on account of the single sin which this
> man commits he and the whole world lose much good.

It is also often quoted in the name of Rambam who synthesizes the two statements (H. Teshubha 3:4):

> צריך כל אדם שיראה עצמו כל השנה כולה כאילו חציו זכאי וחציו חייב. וכן כל
> העולם חציו זכאי וחציו חייב. חטא חטא אחד הרי הכריע את עצמו ואת כל העולם
> כולו לכף חובה וגרם לו השחתה. עשה מצוה אחת הרי הכריע את עצמו ואת כל
> העולם כולו לכף זכות וגרם לו ולהם תשועה והצלה שנאמר וצדיק יסוד עולם זה
> שצדק הכריע את כל העולם לזכות והצילו.
>
> Throughout the entire year, a person should always look at himself as equally balanced between merit and sin and the world as equally balanced between merit and sin. If he performs one sin, he tips his balance and that of the entire world to the side of guilt and brings destruction upon himself. [On the other hand,] if he performs one mitzvah, he tips his balance and that of the entire world to the side of merit and brings deliverance and salvation to himself and others. This is implied by [Proverbs 10:25] "A righteous man is the foundation of the world," i.e., he who acted righteously, tipped the balance of the entire world to merit and saved it.

Comment: Yes, I had heard similar thoughts before.  For example, Rav Nachman of Breslov used to say:  
הַיּוֹם בּוֹ נוֹלַדְתָּ
הוּא הַיּוֹם בּוֹ הֶחְלִיט הקב"ה
שֶׁהָעוֹלָם אֵינוֹ יָכוֹל לְהִתְקַיֵּים בַּלְעֲדֶיךָ
The day that you were born is the day God decided the world could not be preserved without you. -- But I didn't know it was in Chazal.

Answer (score -2):

The future does not depend on any single person except perhaps the Messiah. But as Rabbi Hillel said, "If not me, who? If not now when?"

Or did he? The actual quote seems to be

> If I am not for myself, who is for me? But if I
> am for my own self [only], what am I? And if not now, when?
> [Pirkei_Avot.1.14](https://www.sefaria.org/Pirkei_Avot.1.14?lang=en&with=all&lang2=en)

The first quote fits better, and who knows if he might have said it somewhere too?

The point (for me) is that even if everyone can't be a [Tzadik Hador](https://www.mpaths.com/2009/01/tzaddik-hador.html) at least everyone can try to be.

Comment: "The future does not depend on any single person except perhaps the Messiah. " How so?

Comment: I mean in the sense that the Messiah is the one who ushers in the World to Come. But I accept the idea that he needs help.

Comment: The messiah will be a man who serves a designated function. The qorbanoth are not brought without kohanim. The beth-din does not exist without shofetim. The existence of the future is not dependent on the roles these men play.